# Google feeds - Invalid Unique Product Identifier

Tags: php, feed, uniqueidentifier

I have a google feed in text file. When i upload on Google Merchant, it shows 90 products having problem of "Invalid Unique Product Identifier". Can any one please tell me whats the matter or issue ?

Thanks,
Zain Reza

Answer (score -1):

I can't say for sure without knowing more of the specifics of the feed you're sending over, but I did find this page that might shed some light:  http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160161

From that; it sounds like you're falling into one of these categories:

- Too many or too few digits
- Letters or symbols (instead of numbers only)
- Invalid check digit

When we got this issue; the most common reason for us is that we have internal UPC's that we use (i.e. they're exclusive products for us, so there isn't a registered UPC code for it; unlike if you go to a retail store and look at the back of a candy bar).  (Per the documentation, you can request exemptions for those)

I'd probably start there, and then make sure that i don't have any letters/symbols, and then move on to make sure you're sending the proper number of digits over.